# Any reason why Fixed Size Buffers do not support unmanaged Types?

Tags: c#, .net

Something like this wont compile even though the size of the generic type will be constant

```
public unsafe struct CornerData<T> where T : unmanaged {
    private fixed T _data[4]; // CS1663: Fixed size buffer type must be one of the following: bool, byte, short, int, long, char, sbyte, ushort, uint, ulong, float or double [Assembly-CSharp]
}
```

Is there any reason why fixed size buffers do not allow other types included with the `unmanaged` keyword or could this be an oversight when the keyword was introduced?

Comment: Basically what you ask is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18839085/5311735

Comment: @Evk this seems to be dated as the unmanaged keyword did not exist back then. for example it is possible to use `sizeof()` as long as the struct qualifies as `unmanaged` these days

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it was left out but is now in the works

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/9586b1e3388e367d62c2d3314306c4ed6920d873/proposals/fixed-sized-buffers.md