Fixed size byte array with fixed offset inside manually marshalled struct throws runtime exception?
Target is to have the following struct working in C# (.net 8.0)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 257, Pack = 1)]
    public struct MyFrame
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)] public byte valueA;
      [FieldOffset(1)] public byte valueB;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 254)]
      [FieldOffset(2)] public byte[] valueArray;
      [FieldOffset(256)] public byte valueC;
    }

Program compiles but throws error message during initialisation.

System.TypeLoadException
HResult=0x80131522
Message=Could not load type 'MyFrame' from assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 2 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.
Source=MyAssemböy
StackTrace:
at MyAssembly.MyClass..ctor()
...

My understanding was, that using a pack size of 1 this should be possible.
It compiles and runs, if i move valueArray to start at offset 8, but i want to have it at 2.
Ideally I would also like to extend it union like to this
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 258, Pack = 1)]
    public struct MyFrame
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)] public byte valueA;
      [FieldOffset(1)] public byte valueB;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1,  SizeConst = 254)]
      [FieldOffset(2)] public byte[] valueArray;
      [FieldOffset(256)] public byte valueC;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1,  SizeConst = 257)]
      [FieldOffset(0)] public byte[] rawBytes;
    }

How can I solve this?

ByValArray doesn't mean that the struct as it exists in C# has an inline arary. The array is still a reference type, and the contents of the array will still live on the CLR heap. It means that when the struct is marshalled to C (so an equivalent C struct is created, and the contents of the C# struct copied over by the marshaller), that the C struct will have an inline array, and the marshaller will copy the contents of the C# heap-allocated array into the inline array in the C struct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/inline-arrays might be of interest

You can't have overlapping reference-type objects, so you can't have the array overlapping anything else. Overlapping is an issue in the managed version, rather than the unmanaged version.
It would overlap here because the FieldOffset affects the managed version as well.
But you don't need to use LayoutKind.Explicit, you can use Sequential
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct MyFrame
{
    public byte valueA;
    public byte valueB;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 254)]
    public byte[] valueArray;
    public byte valueC;
}


I need to serialize the struct into a serial data stream and back with these exact offsets, otherwise it would be easy - or did i miss anything else? - In addition i have multiple of these structs. Good hint anyway pointing at the managed overlapping issue. Thanks

Those exact offsets appear to be sequential, so what's the problem? Do you have a different struct where it's not sequential? If so please show.

Please see my union remark at the end of the question, where i would like to have it as a union with either possibility to access the elements by name or the raw value of the complete struct for sending or receiving it over a serial line. but if there is a other, simple way to convert the struct to /from a linear byte buffer , then also fine. I would have hoped to avoid the serialisation/deserialisation using dedicated functions.

I don't think you can do that because of the overlapping buffers. Either way you would need to use the Marshal methods to copy in/out so it makes little difference. In .NET 8 you can use fixed buffers if you want unsafe code but you can only use primitive types not structs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839085/why-can-fixed-size-buffers-only-be-of-primitive-types
