# What is right way to work with fixed size buffers (arrays) in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, unsafe

I have following unmanaged (c++) struct:

```
struct parsed_data_struct
{
    int some_number;  
    float some_array[4]; 
};
```

And I have to call the function (in c++ dll) which fill array of the structs with values:

```
void parse_data (parsed_data_struct* parsed_data);
```

I've found way to make structs with array blittable by using  [fixed size buffers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx)

So my managed struct is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct ParsedDataStruct
{
    public int some_number; 
    public fixed float some_array[4];

}
```

and calling code is

```
    public void Parse(ParsedDataStruct[] parsedData)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (ParsedDataStruct* parsedDataPtr = parsedData)
            {
                parse_data(parsedDataPtr);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx) and [other resources](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fixed-buffer) require fixing structs array to work with them. But I've saw [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881422/why-is-a-fixed-size-buffers-arrays-must-be-unsafe) example of accessing to this kind array without fixing it.

So I have some questions:

1. Is my example right? Is there enough fixing of array of structs?
2. Is there need to fix structs array to access to it elements?

Comment: You don't need to use unsafe pointers in c#.  Create a 2nd structure which contains ParseDataStruct[] parseDataStruct .  You can then declare the array to be a pointer using a [.....] definition.

Comment: [Interesting what happens if you try to write without `fixed`](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4OwzghgZgpgBGALgJ2AY0XAsgTwELBSzICwAUAN7lw1wAOwARgDYCWacUrAHjACZw0ACwjJOPfgSIxkAbQCMAJgAcAXQDc5AL7lyoSLEHMIYMNhwBhY6fJUytekzYdcU4nAC2+Qu4C8cPhgoCGBmRAAKVx8ZAEpNMh0yclYQRBkQCGYjEzMABWQAewBzZAgPW2paJAhEdjgANwLWASwIFPCYypo7BwdcKxzPSzh/EBgAd3MB0w74rt79aBh5hx7e9frRIcYRoYsAOi83GXU4FfXt/a5ePmO5AAZVXYByPGe5+wuHa/44cOFRAAqQQiZC5FC7LwHI7RZBXCS3WGdT5fbrnVFwQEAsEQ/zPACC73RvUSX1JtESiSAA===): a `FixedElementField` appears in the assignment...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you don't need to use unsafe and pointers in such situation in C#. But there is a problem in your code. But in your C++ code. Your struct (shouldn't it be class?) in C# is packed. Your struct in C++ is not. You should pack it too:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

//struct definition here

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Well, no, the other way around, the C# declaration should not use Pack.  It does not actually make any difference, layout is the same for any Pack value.