# c# How do I create a long (>128 bytes for example) field in a structure without using arrays. I can't have any reference type fields in the structure

Tags: c#, structure, memory-mapped-files

In c# I created a  MemoryMappedViewAccessor  and a structure. I want to read from the accessor into the structure. The  structure contains all fixed length fields corresponding to the layout of the original file.  I use only C# Integral numeric types (i.e. byte, ushort, uint, ulong) for all fields because `acessor.Read<T>(struct)` requires that no field be a reference type however, some of the data from the original file must be larger than the largest value type available to me. I cannot use any arrays (i.e. byte[]) since no field can be a reference type.

Comment: Why not use multiple `long` fields in a giant struct to fill the space you need?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [fixed size buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#fixed-size-buffers).

You can create a structure that contains a number of bytes inline:

```cs
struct Structure
{
    unsafe fixed byte largeField[256];
}
```

They are *not* actual arrays, C# stores all those bytes inline in the struct. The accesses to its elements are simply pointer offsets. It's unsafe, since it is not a real array, there is no bounds checking, you can overrun the stack – see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881422/why-is-a-fixed-size-buffers-arrays-must-be-unsafe).

It gets compiled roughly to the equivalent of:

```cs
struct Structure
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 256)]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [UnsafeValueType]
    public struct <largeField>e__FixedBuffer
    {
        public byte FixedElementField;
    }

    [FixedBuffer(typeof(char), 128)]
    public <largeField>e__FixedBuffer largeField;
}
```

As you can see the result contains no reference types, so you can use that with `MemoryMappedViewAccessor`.