# Why does C# consider this unmanaged struct to have an an overlap

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I've defined a struct for an externally defined data-packet as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size=18, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
struct FlexTransmission
{
    [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4, SizeConst =4)]
       public UInt32 transmissionTime;
    [FieldOffset(4),MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 13)]
       public byte[] flexData;           // size 13 bytes
    [FieldOffset(17)]
       public byte transmissionNumber;
}
```

However this structure is considered in error by the compiler (# 11, .NET 7):

**System.TypeLoadException:** 'Could not load type 'Flex.FlexTransmission' from assembly 'Flex, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'

I can't see where the overlap could be.  Surely an UInt32 doesn't take up more than 4 bytes in C# ?

Comment: `System.TypeLoadException` seems to be a runtime error, not C# compiler one.

Comment: Created a Net 7 Console App and instantiated a FlexTransmission in it and simply works? So when do you get this? Some special project settings you use?

Comment: My error sorry. If i actually use the type and not only instantiate it it will fail with the shown exception. Tricked by the optimization :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit layout is about how the data is stored in the managed space, and that has the demand that references must be aligned to the reference size. In reality, you simply shouldn't use explicit layout for anything containing a reference - and the array here: is a reference.

I wonder if instead of using a `byte[]`, you should have used a *fixed buffer*; *that* doesn't have this restriction:

```cs
public unsafe fixed byte flexData[13];
```

Comment: "Explicit layout is about how the data is stored in *both* the managed *and unmanaged* space"

Comment: Also would have thought the `Pack` would have prevented an overlap

Comment: @erict [Why fixed buffer is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881422/why-must-fixed-size-buffers-arrays-be-declared-unsafe)

Comment: @Charlieface with explicit field layout, it doesn't really get much of a vote

Comment: @Charlieface I didn't express it well, but: yes; what I was trying to convey (poorly) is that the "marshal" bits *don't* matter here - it is the managed layout that the JIT is complaining about (on behalf of the GC), which in this case is dominated by the explicit field layout